# TypeError: restaurantMenu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'restaurant_id'

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the flask framework for the development, on executing it is giving following error

> TypeError: restaurantMenu() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'restaurant_id'`

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Base, Restaurant, MenuItem

app = Flask(__name__)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///restaurantmenu.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>/')
def restaurantMenu(restaurant_id):
    restaurant = session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id)
    items = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(restaurant_id=restaurant.id)

    return render_template('menu.html',restaurant=restaurant,items=items)

# Task 1: Create route for newMenuItem function here


@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>/new/')
def newMenuItem(restaurant_id):
    return "page to create a new menu item. Task 1 complete!"

# Task 2: Create route for editMenuItem function here


@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>/<int:menu_id>/edit/')
def editMenuItem(restaurant_id, menu_id):
    return "page to edit a menu item. Task 2 complete!"

# Task 3: Create a route for deleteMenuItem function here


@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>/<int:menu_id>/delete/')
def deleteMenuItem(restaurant_id, menu_id):
    return "page to delete a menu item. Task 3 complete!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: Which route are you using when you see this error?

Comment: From where I can see that...??

Answer (score 1):

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>/')
def restaurantMenu(restaurant_id):
```

Here.
Let's say your site is located at http://bacon.egg/.

So you can access to `restaurantMenu()` view from `http://bacon.egg/` and `http://bacon.egg/<restaurant-id>/`.

But, `restaurantMenu` expect one positional argument (`restaurant_id`). Which is not provided when accessing by route `http://bacon.egg/`

Ok so how to fix it, you can either delete `@app.route('/')` or make `restaurant_id` parameter optional (`def restaurantMenu(restaurant_id = None)`).

- If you removes `@app.route('/')` you will not access to this view with URL http://bacon.egg/ but only with http://bacon.egg/restaurant-id
- If you makes `restaurant_id`'s parameter of `restaurantMenu` optional you will access to the view with both URLs with *this* error, but you surely will needs to handle new errors.

I would recommend the first solution simply because it's less puzzling for user and less tricky to handle for you.

Basically, most of people expect to land on a home-page or a list of restaurant when browsing the root's page of this kind of websites. Moreover keeping things simple and easy to understand is always a good practice in development.

Comment: The real question is why the root of the site expecting nothing is the same as a restaurant which does... Looks like the route of `/` should list the restaurants or something... having something called `restaurantMenu` that expects something to work on also expected to serve `/` is just odd.

Comment: To be honest, most of new-generation-internet-website features / design / vision are all odd for me.. But, well, it's personal. Why if you are a McDonalds and you wants that when people go to disgusting.com/ they land on closest restaurant according to their IP location, and when going into disgusting.com/123 you land on 123 id restaurant. To me it's useless, but people likes this kind of features now.. I'm not here to tell OP what he should likes or not..

Comment: Of course... but the responsibility for that shouldn't necessarily be in the same handler whose purpose is to list a specific restaurant's menu

Comment: Well, I know you are right and I see your point. You win against my lazyness - I will update my answer :)

Comment: @jon I done what i could (it's easier to speak Python than English for me) - don't hesitate to update my answer - you got the idea. _Long live to good fella Moderators._